# Move to previous given line in code

Tags: c#

I  need to run the same code if a particulate exception is occurred. So I tried using `goto`, but with `goto` statement I cant move to a line before the `goto` statement is located

Sample code,

```
try
{
    top:

    //Code

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.Substring(1, 5) == "error")
    {
        goto top: //Error - Can not resolve symbol `top`
        goto bottom: //OK
    }
}

bottom:
    //Code
}
```

How to execute a previous line of code?

Comment: Why not just handle the code by exception? (i.e check the exception you looking for and then handle it accordinly)?

Comment: Place your `top` label before the `try`.

Comment: It is because the label `top:` is inside the `Try`, move it above the `Try` statement

Comment: @KingKing, iabbot Thanks... didn't think it was scope...

Comment: This is a prime example of misusing `goto` imo, Hexie is right, handle the exception correctly, then don't go to bottom, let your code flow, oh and catch the real exception

Comment: Put the whole thing inside while lop, and execute the loop again on some condition, break otherwise.

Comment: @KingKing If you add your comment as a answer I'll accept it cause you answered it first... :)

Comment: @Sayse, In my actual code I do not goto bottom line. I added it just to say it works, but not the top.

Comment: @Nalaka526 thanks, you may want to accept another answer already given below :) (It's up to you)

Comment: @Nalaka526 by 1 second :P

Comment: @iabbott Of course... Up voted your comment.. I tried adding the comment to both of you but SO does not allow to add two users to the same comment, so I added only the 'KingKing' because his comment was above your comment (didn't see the time actually...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code can be easily re written as the following.

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
          //Code
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message.Substring(1, 5) == "error")
        {
            continue;
            //goto bottom; //This doesn't makes sense after we transfer control 
        }
        else
        {
             break;//Did you mean this?
        }
     }
}
```

As pointed in comments it is a good idea to use some counter to prevent continuous looping in case of failure.

Comment: Maybe include an increment counter as a failsafe `while(i < 100)`.. +1 though

Comment: @Sayse No such counter shown in Op's code. So why to be over smart ;)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I guess we should add `break;` at the end of the try block, otherwise it will loop forever..??

Comment: Yes if you don't want to continue when no exception you've to add `break` at the end of `try block`

Comment: It sure is an easy rewrite, but it's certainly not as readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
top:
try
{


    //Code

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.Substring(1, 5) == "error")
    {
        goto top: //Error - Can not resolve symbol `top`
        goto bottom: //OK
    }
}

bottom:
    //Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or try this:

```
public void MyMethod(int count = 0)
{
    if (count > 100)
    { 
        //handle error
        return
    }

    try
    {
        //something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message.Substring(1, 5) == "error")
            MyMethod(++count);
    }

    //other stuff
}
```

Comment: Will result in `StackOverflowException` in case of exception condition matches :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reiterate or rerun the code then do so wrapped in a while loop. That's what it is for.

Here is one easy to understand example:

```
var isDone = false;
while(!isDone) {
    try {
        // code
        isDone = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
      if (ex.Message.Substring(1, 5) == "error")
      {
        continue; // shortcuts it back to the beginning of the while loop
      }
      // other exception handling
      isDone = true;
    }
}
```